# ImageResizer get resized image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm new with Imageresizer from imageresizing.net and i can't figure out how to get the resized image. I need the resized image because i need to add a watermark to it. I need the bitmap of the resized image.

Code:

```
 string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Gags"), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

var ResizedImage = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(UploadGagModel.file, fileName, new Instructions("maxwidth=556&maxheight=1500"), false, true));
```

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 C#

Thanks in advance, if i wasn't clear enough then please tell me!

Comment: This is what i tried: Bitmap ResizedImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ImageBuilder.Current.GetStreamFromSource(UploadGagModel.file, new ResizeSettings("width=200;height=200;format=jpg;mode=max"), ref test2, out test, out test2)); But it doesn't resize the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using System.Drawing directly at all costs - it [is fraught with memory leaks, concurrency issues, and encoding bugs](http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls). ImageResizer handles and avoids these for you, and offers a [Watermarking plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/watermark) as well as SampleOverlay sample plugins to show you how to safely create your own if Watermark can't support your needs.

If, despite my warning, you want to get a Bitmap result, you can pass `typeof(Bitmap)` as the 'destination' parameter to ImageJob, and access the Bitmap instance from the `.Result` property.

Other consequences:

- The Bitmap instance will not be disposed reliably unless you dispose it within a `finally(){}` block (use a temporary variable to cross the scope boundary).
- ImageResizer will not help you with encoding the result. If you call .Save(), you will get gigantic jpeg files, and no 8-bit PNG or animated gif support.
- You will not be able to take advantage of any other pipelines (WIC, FreeImage, etc). Most of our future development will be on better pipelines than GDI+/System.Drawing.